# I am not able build xaml defination build in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When I was trying to queue my xaml nuild it is showing "T" in sourceversion column. I was able to do some time before but now it is showing this error. What can I do? I checked in security of collection level. I am not a member of any Project Collection Build Administrators or Project Collection Build Service Accounts. Is this is the real cause of not able to build. Please suggest me.

Attaching screenshot also:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIbRi.png)

Comment: "T" means "most recent version" but it hasn't determined what the most recent version is yet. If the build is hanging at this point, the first step is to restart the build controller.

Comment: Is the permission level is not the problem for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the build worked before. The permission level should not be the problem caused that.

Versionspec "T" means the latest version, the build task will execute "`tf get /version:T`" command that will get the latest version of your source code. Refer to [tf get command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command#parameters) for details:

> /version:versionspec
>
> Specifies the maximum version, or the minimum and the maximum
>   versions, to display in the history data. The default is **/version:T**
>   (the latest version).

Generally the source version displays as "T" for a few seconds (hangs for a while ) when the build is triggered and then changes to the latest version.

Based on the screenshot you posted, seems the build process hangs there when obtaining the latest version of the source.

So, you can try to restart the build controller, if that still not work, just try to unregister the build services then register the build services again. Or try another build controller.